# Trouble with text over an image in IE

Tags: html, css

I have some trouble putting just simple text over an image in IE. The image has a lower z-index than the text so I am not sure what it can be. I also tried to give the text a relative position rather than a absolute one. But it’s still not working. Has anybody please any ideas??

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question with the code you're using at the moment?

Comment: could you provide some markup and css?

Comment: It would be much easier to answer that question, It you posted some code. Also, I'm wondering what this problem has to do with javascript?

Comment: Starting to accept some of the answered offered to you would also make it likely to get help. (0%--come on!)

Answer (score 2):

IE doesn't handle z-index as the standard states. The best solution is to put the image as a background-image property to a container (for example a div) and the text inside that div. This way all the browsers recognize the correct order.

The second solution is to place both the img and the span (containing the text) in a div with the following properties:

```
<div style="position:relative">
  <img src="a.jpg" style="position:absolute;" />
  <span style="position:absolute">your text here</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the image and text in a div container set to 'relative' position.
Set the image to position 'absolute'
The text will appear ontop of the image

To control the text put it in another div and use the margin property to move it.

```
<div id="container" style="position: relative;">
     <img style="position: absolute;" src="#" />
     <div id="textcontainer" style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px">
          Text to float on image here
     </div>
</div>
```

No need for z-index :) Different versions of IE don't like it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" title="Text over image here">
```

Comment: i think he means text from a different tag

Comment: And you know this because you can read his mind? I answered his question of "how to put simple text over an image" perfectly given the information he gave. No reason to neg the answer.

Comment: we all neg for no reason, don't we?